# Can you auto-fill a custom field when a product becomes out of stock? CE2.3.2

Tags: magento2.3, custom-attributes

I have a custom text-field called 'Back in stock' (in orange) which displays on the product grid once a product is out of stock and the field has content.

[image: ![enter image description here]

My question is: is there a way of automatically setting that field to 'T.B.C' for example, once a product becomes out of stock? I would then need to be able to change it manually once I had a date available.

TIA

Answer (score -1):

You can add the custom stock status in the quick edit by using the following filter in theme's functions.php

```
function add_custom_stock_type_in_quick_edit( $status ) {
    return array(
        'instock' => __( 'In stock', 'woocommerce' ),
        'exhibited' => __( 'Exhibited', 'woocommerce' ),
        'sold' => __( 'Sold', 'woocommerce' ),
    );
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_stock_status_options', 'add_custom_stock_type_in_quick_edit' );
```

Comment: This is a WordPress solution to a Magento question, hence not relevant at all here.